# Auto save all visited pages in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

I searched for this on Google, but I could not find it. So is there any add-on which automatically saves all the pages I visit in some cache, so that I can access them in offline mode also?

I am using [Firefox 8.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Firefox#Version_8) and [Ubuntu 10.10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_10.10_.28Maverick_Meerkat.29) (Maverick Meerkat).

Comment: Have you tried [scrapbook](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scrapbook/)

Comment: or ReadItLater add-on has an offline capability, but does not save pages automatically. Only one click to do so for each page though.

Comment: @Raystafarian good one :-)

Comment: There is something but for chrome https://github.com/idibidiart/AllSeeingEye

Comment: This question might be useful: https://superuser.com/questions/1139864/how-can-i-cache-all-pages-i-visit-with-firefox

Answer (score 3):

[Shelve](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/shelve/) seems to be what you're looking for.